# Using lazy property fetching in Grails / Gorm

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, fetch

is there any way to use lazy property fetching in Grails / Gorm ?
somtehing like:

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

annotation
( it also works with left join fetch?)

(for example lazy loading of an String attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked on the grails-user mailing list [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Lazy-fetching-in-just-one-property-of-the-Domain-Class-td1577445.html). There are a few different options discussed.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.5.2.8%20Eager%20and%20Lazy%20Fetching

**EDIT**

By the way have you tried?:

```
static mapping = {
    property lazy:true
}
```

Comment: This solves only the problem with the associations, what I need is, to load lazy for example a String attribute.

Comment: take a look at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties maybe you need to do the mapping in xml in order to enable lazy properties. Alternatively smacking a @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) on the property or the getter might do the trick. You must however enable hibernate annotations in grails. (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html)

Comment: Thx, this worked for me!!, the only problem is that you cannot use these annotations on grails domain classes, and run the instrumentation on it.

Comment: @csviri what worked for u and how did u get it working - can u comment please