# Tree structure in GORM (grails)

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm trying to define a tree structure in GORM. Here is my model:

```
class Tree {
    String name
    Level rootLevel

    static hasOne = [rootLevel: Level]
    static hasMany = [levels: Level]
    static mappedBy = [levels:"parentTree"]
}

class Level {
    String name
    Tree parentTree
    Level parentLevel
    Set<Level> subLevels

    static belongsTo = [parentTree: Tree]
    static hasMany = [subLevels: Level]
}
```

Insertion seems to work fine, but when I can't load a Tree with many levels and sublevels.
I guess I missed something in the relations:
- the Tree should have a reference to the rootLevel (and optionally to all sublevels)
- a Level should have a reference to its parent level, its sublevels and the global parent Tree

Could you point me out the right direction to get a tree structure like this ?
Thanks

Comment: Hibernate doesn't like recursive structures but it's possible. Please explain what you mean by "but when I can't load a Tree with many levels and sublevels". Do you get an error or what?

Comment: The problem is that levels are filled with the parent Tree id, but when you load the Tree, you have the following error "More than one row with the given identifier was found" for the Level class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with this solution (thanks to a friend):

```
class Tree {
   String name
   Level rootLevel

   static hasMany = [levels: Level]
   static mappedBy = [rootLevel: "parentTree", levels: "owningTree"]

   static constraints = {rootLevel(nullable: true)}
}
```

and

```
class Level {
   String name
   Tree parentTree
   Tree owningTree
   Level parentLevel
   Set<Level> subLevels

   static belongsTo = [owningTree: Tree, parentLevel: Level]
   static hasMany = [subLevels: Level]
   static mappedBy = [parentTree: "rootLevel", owningTree: "levels", subLevels: "parentLevel"]

   static constraints = {
       parentTree(nullable: true)
       parentLevel(nullable: true)
   }
}
```

I was missing the two relations between Tree and Level (owningTree and parentTree) and some mappedBy configuration to help hibernate.

Answer (score 11):

I didn't like your tree structure, so i created my own :)

```
Class TreeNode {
    String name
    TreeNode parent

    static hasMany = [children: TreeNode]

    //returns the root node, and by extension, the entire tree!
    TreeNode getRootNode(){
       if(parent){
          //if parent is not null then by definition this node is a child node of the tree.
          return parent.getRootNode()
       }else{
          //if parent is null then by definition it is the root node.
          return this
       }
    }

    //you might not need this function, but ill add it as it is common in tree structures
    boolean isLeaf(){
       //determines if this node is a leaf node. a leaf is a node with zero childrens
       return children.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

As for ensuring that all treenodes is loaded, you can always use eager/non-lazy fetching for each treeNode both parent and children. Could however have a performance penalty if your tree structures are very large...

As for eager/lazy fetching. take a look here: [Using lazy property fetching in Grails / Gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880564/using-lazy-property-fetching-in-grails-gorm/5880599#5880599)

Comment: thanks for your reply. Indeed with that approach, you avoid the mess with relationship between Tree, Level and sublevels. But as you said, there is no direct reference to the parent Tree, which is not the best scenario for me.

Comment: There is a direct reference to the parent tree, but not the root tree, if that is what you ment. However, fetching the root tree is possible from each TreeNode instance. Alternatively you could always add an explicit reference to the root node by adding `TreeNode rootNode` to the class definition. Any reason why my original porposal is not the best scenario for you?

Comment: Another solution is to set

    `TreeNode getRootNode(){
        String hql = "From TreeNode where parent is null"
        return TreeNode.execureQuery(hql)  
     }`

Comment: the recursive way to retrieve the root TreeNode comes with a performance penalty as you said. But with your last option, that could definitely work.

Comment: Try it and see how my solution works. And if you have any other questions, im happy to help.

Comment: In this case, should we add the static mappedBy to name the properties to specify which collection mappedBy as parent? `Class TreeNode{ ....static mappedBy = [children:'parent'] .... } ` Or I am wrong?

Comment: @netbrain I couldn't get it to work. I get this error: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
    Line | Method

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that levels are filled with the parent Tree id, but when you load the Tree, you have the following error "More than one row with the given identifier was found" for the Level class.

Your problem seems to be that you have more than a single root node for each tree. This is an unusual approach. To make it work, you must replace `Level rootLevel` in the entity `Tree` with `Set<Level> roots`.

Comment: that's why I have both hasOne and hasMany. The purpose it to have fully linked structure: access to the rootLevel and all possibles sublevels from the Tree, access to the parentLevel from a Level and access to the Tree from any level.

Comment: The Hibernate error means "The entity TREE has several children of type LEVEL but the field in the Java class is just a single reference". So you must have added several root nodes to the same tree.