# Tree-Like Structure in Grails GORM

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I want to create a tree-like structure in Grails GORM. The structure should be a container for other objects and should full fill the following requirements:

- a node should have 0 to n childrens
- a node should have exactly one parent node
- a node should have 0 to n sibling nodes

How can I define such a structure in Grails GORM?

I tried the following class:

```
Class TreeNode {
    String name
    TreeNode parent

    static hasMany = [children: TreeNode]

    //returns the root node, and by extension, the entire tree!
    TreeNode getRootNode(){
       if(parent){
          //if parent is not null then by definition this node is a child node of the tree.
          return parent.getRootNode()
       }else{
          //if parent is null then by definition it is the root node.
          return this
       }
    }

    //you might not need this function, but ill add it as it is common in tree structures
    boolean isLeaf(){
       //determines if this node is a leaf node. a leaf is a node with zero childrens
       return children.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

But on startup I get the following error:

```
ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsDomainException: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2013-10-04 17:36:00,730 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
Message: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsDomainException: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GrailsDomainException: Property [children] in class [class test.TreeNode] is a bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the relationship [treeNode] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static mappedBy = [children:'myprop']
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tree structure in GORM (grails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880672/tree-structure-in-gorm-grails)

Comment: @tim_yates Not every question to the same topic is a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree generally has one parent per node.  You can define a tree node having a one-to-many relationship to itself like this:

```
class TreeNode {
    TreeNode parent
    static hasMany = [children: TreeNode]
    static mappedBy = [children: 'parent']
}
```

If it has multiple parents, it's not actually a tree in the computer science sense.  This data structure is usually called a directed graph.  You might be able to model it as a many to many relationship to itself, like this:

```
class GraphNode {
    static hasMany = [children: GraphNode]
    static hasMany = [parents: GraphNode]
    static mappedBy = [children: 'parents', parents: 'children']
}
```

Comment: How to I insert and delete Nodes? How do I extend the relationships with properties like dateCreated?

Comment: To insert and delete, the same as any other grails domain object.  In the `GraphNode` example, call `node.addToParents(parent)` or `node.addToChildren(child)` to add a parent or child before saving.  If you want properties on the relationship itself, you're better off modelling the relationship as a separate entity, e.g. `GraphNode` and `GraphEdge`.

Comment: Add in the `mappedBy` to tell gorm `children` is mapped through `parent`.

Comment: this does not wokr since I have a different class than you posted.

Comment: Add this to the class you posted: `static mappedBy = [children: 'parent']`.

Answer (score 0):

ataylor is right. TO describe relations, you have to use 2 Domain classes:

```
class Node {
    static hasMany = [relations: Relation]
}
class Relation {
    Node fromNode
    Node toNode
    String name //ex. 'son'
    String reverseName // ex. 'father'
}
```

Comment: I think, you need to add 'static belongsTo = [parent:TreeNode]'